# How to format the given xml into single line (without spaces)

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

Using C# how can i format a given xml file into a single single line (without spaces)?

My output is giving symbols if there are spaces and new lines.

Comment: Are you talking about writing the ouput to another file?

Comment: Show of your input xml data, and out-put formation you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
public static string StripXmlWhitespace(string Xml)
{
    Regex Parser = new Regex(@">\s*<");
    Xml = Parser.Replace(Xml, "><");

    return Xml.Trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string's Replace method to format xmlString and then save it to output:

```
string singleLineXml = xml.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ")
```

or

```
string singleLineXml = xml.Replace("\r\n", " ")
```

After removing line breaks > remove spaces:

```
singleLineXml.Remove(' ');
```

Yes @Steve Wellens, Remove(' ') is a bad idea.. let's try

```
singleLineXml.Replace("> <","><");
```

And i found relative thread, may be it helps [Writing string to XML file without formatting (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991561/writing-string-to-xml-file-without-formatting-c)

Comment: That will remove space from inside the nodes.

Comment: I am using XmlDocument to read the whole xml, hence i am not having the Remove or Replace property.